# Appium: getting device time (python, real, device ios)

Tags: python, ios, appium

Can somebody help me.I need to get current device time in runtime (there is some functionality which depends on device time).

I am using appium 1.6.3, iOS 10.2 (real device), python 2.7.10
I have tried following:

self.driver.device_time
=> 'Invalid Date'

from appium.webdriver.webdriver import WebDriver
a = WebDriver.device_time
=> a = `<property object at 0x10b69f158>` 
             `fdel ={NoneType} None`
             `fset ={NoneType} None`

Comment: using datetime, `import datetime` `datetime.datetime.now()`

Comment: Are you sure? it will return your system time (e.g PC or laptop), not the device time.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to import webdriver:

```
from appium import webdriver
```

Then you have to create your webdriver object

```
self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities={
        'app': 'http://appium.s3.amazonaws.com/TestApp7.1.app.zip',
        'platformName': 'iOS',
        'platformVersion': '10.3',
        'deviceName': 'iPhone Simulator'
    })
```

Once you have your webdriver object instantiated it is as simple as:

```
self.driver.device_time
```

You do need to have **libimobiledevice** installed because that comes with a binary called **idevicedate** which is used for this call.